# Is there a simple algorithm for solving Kami 2 puzzles?

Tags: pattern, geometry, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm finding my life has been consumed by [Kami 2](http://www.stateofplaygames.com/kami2/), partly because I seem to have achieved some "insight" and am able to solve the puzzles reliably, almost always on the first try.

The rules are simple: *Each move consists of replacing any one contiguous colored region with one of the available colors (from a palette provided). The goal is to have filled the entire image with a single such color in a given number of moves (indicated in the toolbar).*

[image]

But whatever this "insight" is, it's not enlightenment. I don't know why or how I'm doing it, I just am.

I wonder if there is some simple algorithm for solving these puzzles reliably (involving, I assume, some [underlying graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279441/12400)).

Comment: Related: [Will a greedy algorithm solve Tatham's Flood?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46644/will-a-greedy-algorithm-solve-tathams-flood)

Answer (score 5):

[Flood-filling games are, for sufficiently many colours, NP-hard](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4420). There's no known algorithm that's significantly more efficient than brute force with pruning.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented an algorithm [here](https://github.com/brianberns/KamiSolver) that can solve some Kami 2 puzzles quickly. (Specifically, those where the number of available moves is not much higher than the number of colors in the palette.) It's a brute force approach with a few simple heuristics. I think it would be very difficult to design an algorithm that approaches these problems in a human-like way, but perhaps a neural network of some sort could be trained to do it.

Comment: F# though! Haskell would be perfect!

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do the image manipulation in Haskell, and some of the performance optimizations are not purely functional. I could translate it to C# if you'd like.

Comment: No worries. I just wish it were in something I'm set up for (Python, Haskell, Mathematica).

Answer (score 2):

I coded up an A*-based algorithm that solves Kami2 levels. It's described in my blog post [here](https://cmath-school.com/blog/kami2-ai) (with the C++ code). I'm sure there are ways to improve it; would love to hear ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a backtracking algorithm based on Constraint Satisfaction to prune the search space. Here is the link on GitHub [solution](https://github.com/rajeevseb/kami2)
Though it does not use image processing to create the graph it works well on the puzzles I was trying to solve. Maybe can add it during the summer